# Como NÃO arredondar valores no PANDAS?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estou manipulando um DataFrame no Pandas que é um relatório que emito do meu sistema. Como os valores vem em R$ (Real Brasileiro) eu faço um replace da string nos valores substituindo a ',' por '.', depois transformo os valores da coluna em float64. Só que após fazer isso ele não trabalha os valores da minha coluna com exatidão, sempre estão arredondando os valores. Como evitar que isso aconteça?

O DataFrame antes é assim:
[DataFrame antes do Replace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3CDP.png)

```
conc ['SaldoFinal'] = conc ['SaldoFinal'].str.replace(',','.')
conc = conc.astype({'SaldoFinal':'float64'})
conc
```

Após o código fica dessa forma:
[Após o replace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3TDh.png)

Comment: Só para confirmar, o type da coluna SaldoFinal é object? E outra pergunta, esse existe concatenação de DataFrame no seu código?

Comment: Olá, bom dia. Sim, o type da coluna está como object e tem concatenação de DataFrame, o type da outra coluna também é object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendo base no seu [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/568388/como-n%C3%83o-arredondar-valores-no-pandas?noredirect=1#comment1002121_568388) sobre a concatenação e a coluna saldo ser `object`, vou trazer a solução que se adeque no seu cenário.

```
import pandas as pd

# Primeiro DataFrame
conc = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Codigo_Conta": [6398, 6399],
        "ClasMasc": ["11021.01", "1102.1.01.01"],
        "NomeConta": ["Faturado", "Residencial"],
        "SaldoFinal": ["3155584,96", "1620212,90"],
    }
)

# Segundo DataFrame
conc1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Codigo_Conta": [6395],
        "ClasMasc": ["1102156.01"],
        "NomeConta": ["Residencial"],
        "SaldoFinal": ["5555557,96"],
    }
)

# Concatenação entre o primeiro DataFrame e segundo DataFrame
conc = pd.concat([conc, conc1])
```

Output (Coluna SaldoFinal **antes da modificação**):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Transformando a coluna object para float

Antes de passar pelo processo de modificação do type `object` para `float`, é necessário trocar as "," por "." e atribuir o valor para a coluna existente que ocorreu a modificação (sobrescrevendo ela com valores novos).

```
conc['SaldoFinal'] = conc['SaldoFinal'].str.replace(',','.')
```

Com a coluna com os novos valores, basta utilizar o `astype` para modificar para o `float`

```
conc['SaldoFinal'] = conc['SaldoFinal'].astype(float)
```

Para fazer todo esse processo de transformação em **apenas uma linha**, basta utilizar esse código

```
conc['SaldoFinal'] = conc['SaldoFinal'].str.replace(',','.').astype(float)
```

Output (Coluna SaldoFinal após a **modificação**):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ajeita para o AP a pergunta pois se ela receber mais um voto de fechamento será fechada e do jeito que está,dados em links e esclarecimento nos comentários, é candidata a remoção

Comment: Não consigo sugerir edição, a fila de edições sugeridas está cheia